# XA transaction in Spring not handled properly with JMS when throwing RuntimeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms, websphere-liberty

I need XA transactions With IBM Websphere Liberty Core Tx Manager and ActiveMQ as Broker.
Producer works just fine, but consumer is not "rolling back" the message after failure.

Consumer is defined as:

```xml
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

Tx is defined as:

```xml
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

Connection Factory is instance of ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.

My messageListener throws RuntimeException, and this causes flag to be set as ReadOnly in Spring Code. Interesting part is in this Snipped of Spring code:

```java
protected boolean receiveAndExecute(Object invoker, Session session, MessageConsumer consumer)
        throws JMSException {

    if (this.transactionManager != null) {
        // Execute receive within transaction.
        TransactionStatus status = this.transactionManager.getTransaction(this.transactionDefinition);
        boolean messageReceived;
        try {
            messageReceived = doReceiveAndExecute(invoker, session, consumer, status);
        }
        catch (JMSException ex) {
            rollbackOnException(status, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            rollbackOnException(status, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Error err) {
            rollbackOnException(status, err);
            throw err;
        }
        this.transactionManager.commit(status);
        return messageReceived;
    }

    else {
        // Execute receive outside of transaction.
        return doReceiveAndExecute(invoker, session, consumer, null);
    }
}
```

Method doReceiveAndExecute correctly invokes the Listener, and marks Tx as rollbackOnly. However, it then consumes the RuntimeException, as it can be shown in code snipped below so rollbackOnException is not invoked at all.

Here is exception consumer snipped in class AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer

```java
catch (Throwable ex) {
                if (status != null) {
                    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                        logger.debug("Rolling back transaction because of listener exception thrown: " + ex);
                    }
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
                }
                handleListenerException(ex);
                // Rethrow JMSException to indicate an infrastructure problem
                // that may have to trigger recovery...
                if (ex instanceof JMSException) {
                    throw (JMSException) ex;
                }
            }
```

Do I miss something, or is it bug in Spring code or somewhere else? My Spring-jms version is 4.0.5.RELEASE

--- UPDATE ---

We have quite an issue with XA transactions using Active MQ.

We connect from Liberty to Active MQ (remote). If we use WLC TX Manager in XA mode,
**There is no rollback** in Active MQ (in case of Exception).

If we change Tx manager for **Atomikos** Tx manager, **everything works just fine**. (in case of issue, we get rollback, and message stays in Queue...)

So, there probably is an issue with either WLC Tx Manager or WLC Tx Manager in cooperation with XA Connection Factory... :( Well, that means the WLC tx manager has problem to work in Spring+WLC+ActiveMQ+XA stack.

We raised an issue to IBM and waiting for response.

UPDATE:

```
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory cf = (ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory) activeMqInitialContext().lookup("XAConnectionFactory");

        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(500);
        redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
        redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(-1);
        cf.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);

        return cf;
    }

    <bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="eStampMessageListener" class="sk.posta.ekolky.oek.jms.EStampMessageListener" />
```

Comment: The fact that the exception is consumed doesn't matter, the transaction is already marked as rollback only so it will be rolledback any way. Make sure that the JMS infrastructure you use is XA capable next to that you probably also need to set the property `sessionTransacted` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. However, in XA, session is not transacted at all, as transaction as above it, transaction on session level is managed in diferent flow... My point is that, actually `catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            rollbackOnException(status, ex);
            throw ex;
        }` is never invoked. Status is set as rollbackOnly true, but then tx.commit is called. This is quite far beyond my understanding, as code is quite messy, and complicated... I gues someone from Spring-jms team should review it...

Comment: The XA support in spring-jms works just fine as far as I know and I don't really understand what you mentioned. Do you get an exception? Can you share a project that reproduces the problem? If you can, please create an issue and we'll look at it.

Comment: Stéphane Nicoll, you are right, issue seems to be XA manager in websphere... When we replaced it by Atomikos, it worked just fine... However, I still think, that Spring code is just tricky :D

Comment: I suspect that the problem is connected with how the JMS connection factory is being configured. It seems likely that you end up using an unmanaged JMS connection/session which is never enlisted in the transaction. Please could you indicate how the JMS resources are being picked up by Spring? The beans snippet shows references to other beans, but not how those beans are defined. It would help to know if those beans are being picked up from JNDI and a resource reference. It would also be helpful to know how the transaction is started.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, I've just added snippets you want. Only the `queue` is missing, which is pulled via JNDI. Transaction manager is configured as `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`.